# Locale switching in Symfony2/Sylius in frontend

Tags: symfony, locale, frontend, sylius

Please help to configure locale switching in Symfony2/Sylius in frontend,
which for some reason does not work.

Picture here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A new feature was very [recently added to Sylius in 0.12](https://twitter.com/Sylius/status/540591596228870144) to allow translations of certain models in Sylius.

One model domain includes `Taxonomy` and `Taxon` which provides the data for the *Shop By* menu. By default, [Sylius will install translations only for English and Spanish](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/bb22cc3f22055faff47bab21b0c98cde721a3229/src/Sylius/Bundle/FixturesBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadTaxonomiesData.php#L34), and are not handled by Symfony Translation catalogs.

You should be able to change this by visiting the `/administration/taxonomies/` path on your app, then clicking *EDIT* on the Taxonomy, and by following either *Category* or *Brand* taxonomy links and then clicking *EDIT* next to a Taxon.

There you will have the fields for the locales you have configured.

---

### Taxonomy / Categorization in Sylius Administration dashboard

[image: Administration of Sylius Taxonomies]

---

### Editing translation fields for the *Category* Taxonomy

[image: Editing Sylius Taxonomy translation fields]

---

### Viewing taxons for the *Category* taxonomy

[image: Viewing Taxons for a Taxonomy]

Comment: Where is the choice of language: [http://localhost/sylius/sylius-standard/web/app_dev.php/administration/taxonomies/1/taxons/4/edit](http://clip2net.com/s/3bWGwt4)      ?

Comment: @Raisa That's weird you don't get the choices on the Taxon form, I'll have to look into that! But did you see the translation choices for the Taxonomy form?

Comment: @РаисаРезниченко Great! If this solves your question, please mark it as accepted. Cheers :)